# Getting entries from an array in Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming

How can I make this work?

I'm trying to get an entry by passing an argument to a function.

In file findentry.js I have the following code:

```
var elements = [{"ID": "A1", "XX": "A2", "KK": "A3"}, {"ID": "B1", "XX": "B2", "KK": "B3"}];


function getEntry (err, cb) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }
    // console.log(elements[0]);
    function getElement(c, g) {
        return c.ID === g;
    }
    entry = (elements.find(getElement));
    cb(null, entry);
}

module.exports = getEntry;
```

In server.js I do the following:

```
var entry = require('./findentry.js');
var el = "B1";
entry(function (err, el) {
    console.log(err, el)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an additional parameter to `getEntry` that indicates the ID you're trying to find.

```js
var elements = [{
  "ID": "A1",
  "XX": "A2",
  "KK": "A3"
}, {
  "ID": "B1",
  "XX": "B2",
  "KK": "B3"
}];


function getEntry(cb, idToFind) {
  try {
    const entry = elements.find(({ ID }) => ID === idToFind);
    cb(null, entry);
  } catch(err) {
    cb(err);
  }
}


var idToFind = "B1";
getEntry(function(err, el) {
  console.log(err, el)
}, idToFind);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works but I also get a null value just before the entry in the output. How can I remove it?

Comment: You seemed to indicate that you wanted the callback to have an `err` parameter - that's what it's there for. (it'll only throw currently if an element in the array is `null` or `undefined`, or if `elements` isn't an array. If you don't want an `err` parameter, just remove it (as well as the `try`/`catch`)